# The different addressing modes of CUDA textures

Tags: cuda, textures, border, addressing-mode

I am using a CUDA texture in border addressing mode (`cudaAddressModeBorder`). I am reading texture coordinates using `tex2D<float>()`. When the texture coordinates fall outside the texture, `tex2D<float>()` returns `0`.

How can I change this returned border value from `0` to something else? I could check the texture coordinate manually and set the border value myself. I was wondering if there was CUDA API where I can set such a border value.

Comment: The hardware supports setting the color but that is not exposed in CUDA. Probably because none of the classic addressing modes require any extra parameters. NVIDIA has registered it as a requested feature. As a workaround, maybe you can draw a 1 pixel border of the color that you need around the texture and use clamp addressing mode together with tweaked coordinates.

Comment: @RogerDahl I had guessed this is just a CUDA API issue. Because border color can be set in DirectX for the same hardware. In any case, I cannot modify the texture in this particular case, so no solution for me :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As mentioned by sgarizvi, CUDA supports only four, non-customizable address modes, namely, **clamp**, **border**, **wrap** and **mirror**, which are described in Section 3.2.11.1. of the CUDA programming guide.

The former two work in both unnormalized and normalized coordinates, while the latter two in normalized coordinates only.

To describe the first two, let us consider the unnormalized coordinates case and consider 1D signals, for the sake of simplicity. In this case, the input sequence is `c[k]`, with `k=0,...,M-1`.

**cudaAddressModeClamp**

The signal `c[k]` is continued outside `k=0,...,M-1` so that `c[k] = c[0]` for `k < 0`, and `c[k] = c[M-1]` for `k >= M`.

**cudaAddressModeBorder**

The signal `c[k]` is continued outside `k=0,...,M-1` so that `c[k] = 0` for `k < 0`and for `k >= M`.

Now, to describe the last two address modes, we are forced to consider normalized coordinates, so that the 1D input signal samples are assumed to be `c[k / M]`, with `k=0,...,M-1`.

**cudaAddressModeWrap**

The signal `c[k / M]` is continued outside `k=0,...,M-1` so that it is periodic with period equal to `M`. In other words, `c[(k + p * M) / M] = c[k / M]` for any (positive, negative or vanishing) integer `p`.

**cudaAddressModeMirror**

The signal `c[k / M]` is continued outside `k=0,...,M-1` so that it is periodic with period equal to `2 * M - 2`. In other words, `c[l / M] = c[k / M]` for any `l` and `k` such that `(l + k)mod(2 * M - 2) = 0`.

The following code illustrates all the four available address modes

```
#include <stdio.h>

texture<float, 1, cudaReadModeElementType> texture_clamp;
texture<float, 1, cudaReadModeElementType> texture_border;
texture<float, 1, cudaReadModeElementType> texture_wrap;
texture<float, 1, cudaReadModeElementType> texture_mirror;

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

/******************************/
/* CUDA ADDRESS MODE CLAMPING */
/******************************/
__global__ void Test_texture_clamping(const int M) {

    printf("Texture clamping - i = %i; value = %f\n", -threadIdx.x, tex1D(texture_clamp, -(float)threadIdx.x));
    printf("Texture clamping - i = %i; value = %f\n", M + threadIdx.x, tex1D(texture_clamp, (float)(M + threadIdx.x)));

}

/****************************/
/* CUDA ADDRESS MODE BORDER */
/****************************/
__global__ void Test_texture_border(const int M) {

    printf("Texture border - i = %i; value = %f\n", -threadIdx.x, tex1D(texture_border, -(float)threadIdx.x));
    printf("Texture border - i = %i; value = %f\n", M + threadIdx.x, tex1D(texture_border, (float)(M + threadIdx.x)));

}

/**************************/
/* CUDA ADDRESS MODE WRAP */
/**************************/
__global__ void Test_texture_wrap(const int M) {

    printf("Texture wrap - i = %i; value = %f\n", -threadIdx.x, tex1D(texture_wrap, -(float)threadIdx.x/(float)M));
    printf("Texture wrap - i = %i; value = %f\n", M + threadIdx.x, tex1D(texture_wrap, (float)(M + threadIdx.x)/(float)M));

}

/****************************/
/* CUDA ADDRESS MODE MIRROR */
/****************************/
__global__ void Test_texture_mirror(const int M) {

    printf("Texture mirror - i = %i; value = %f\n", -threadIdx.x, tex1D(texture_mirror, -(float)threadIdx.x/(float)M));
    printf("Texture mirror - i = %i; value = %f\n", M + threadIdx.x, tex1D(texture_mirror, (float)(M + threadIdx.x)/(float)M));

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
void main(){

    const int M = 4;

    // --- Host side memory allocation and initialization
    float *h_data = (float*)malloc(M * sizeof(float));

    for (int i=0; i<M; i++) h_data[i] = (float)i;

    // --- Texture clamping
    cudaArray* d_data_clamping = NULL; gpuErrchk(cudaMallocArray(&d_data_clamping, &texture_clamp.channelDesc, M, 1)); 
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyToArray(d_data_clamping, 0, 0, h_data, M * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)); 
    cudaBindTextureToArray(texture_clamp, d_data_clamping); 
    texture_clamp.normalized = false; 
    texture_clamp.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp;

    dim3 dimBlock(2 * M, 1); dim3 dimGrid(1, 1);
    Test_texture_clamping<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(M);

    printf("\n\n\n");

    // --- Texture border
    cudaArray* d_data_border = NULL; gpuErrchk(cudaMallocArray(&d_data_border, &texture_border.channelDesc, M, 1)); 
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyToArray(d_data_border, 0, 0, h_data, M * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)); 
    cudaBindTextureToArray(texture_border, d_data_border); 
    texture_border.normalized = false; 
    texture_border.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeBorder;

    Test_texture_border<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(M);

    printf("\n\n\n");

    // --- Texture wrap
    cudaArray* d_data_wrap = NULL; gpuErrchk(cudaMallocArray(&d_data_wrap, &texture_wrap.channelDesc, M, 1)); 
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyToArray(d_data_wrap, 0, 0, h_data, M * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)); 
    cudaBindTextureToArray(texture_wrap, d_data_wrap); 
    texture_wrap.normalized = true; 
    texture_wrap.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeWrap;

    Test_texture_wrap<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(M);

    printf("\n\n\n");

    // --- Texture mirror
    cudaArray* d_data_mirror = NULL; gpuErrchk(cudaMallocArray(&d_data_mirror, &texture_mirror.channelDesc, M, 1)); 
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyToArray(d_data_mirror, 0, 0, h_data, M * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)); 
    cudaBindTextureToArray(texture_mirror, d_data_mirror); 
    texture_mirror.normalized = true ; 
    texture_mirror.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeMirror;

    Test_texture_mirror<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(M);

    printf("\n\n\n");
}
```

Those are the outputs

```
index                  -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11
clamp                   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0  1  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3   3
border                  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0  1  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
wrap                    1   2   3   0   1   2   3  0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3  0  1   2   3
mirror                  1   2   3   3   2   1   0  0  1  2  3  3  2  1  0  0  1   2   3
```

Comment: I wish this was the cuda documentation and not `cudaTextureDesc::addressMode specifies the addressing mode`!! . Thanks Nvidia ....

Comment: Thanks, very useful.

Answer (score 4):

As of now (CUDA 5.5), the CUDA texture fetch behavior is not customizable. Only 1 of the 4 automatic built-in modes (i.e. **Border**, **Clamp**, **Wrap** and **Mirror**) can be utilized for out of range texture fetch.